# Есть ли в bootstrap кнопки, как в этом фреймворке?

Tags: jquery, framework, javascript, bootstrap

Есть ли в в bootstrap кнопки, как в [этом фреймворке](http://imperavi.com/kube/components/) (первая кнопка переключатель).
Только сегодня видел, а теперь найти не могу. Может показалось?

Просто куб не кроссбраузерный.

Comment: ссылко битое

Comment: Ссылка рабочая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы искать не пробовали?
[Кнопки](http://bootstrap-ru.com/base_css.php#buttons)

**UPD**
[А вот вам переключатели](http://www.larentis.eu/bootstrap_toggle_buttons/)

**P.s.**
юзайте поиск

Comment: Почему-то если вытаскиваю все скрипты и стили в папку, то перестают кнопки работать. Один раз нажимаются, а потом перестают.

Comment: Есть в бутстрапе кнопки такие, как по ссылке? Без эффекта ползунка, просто переключатели?

Comment: Not Animated?

Comment: Нет. Там ползунок имеется. Если кнопка в положении ON, то OFF перекрывается. А нужно, чтобы и ON и OFF были в области видимости. Хотя можно и эти кнопки с ползунком использовать. Только они у меня не работают, если скрипты все на локалке.

Comment: вам наверное [радио от сюда](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) надо

Comment: Да, вариант, что надо. А как её использовать? Где там код самих радио? Чтобы переменные передавать? И можно ли как-то изменить CSS этих кнопок?